# How do memory-mapped files work in a multi-process scenario?

Tags: java, memory, memory-mapped-files, filechannel, mappedbytebuffer

This question has been confusing me for days:

Assume that I have two processes (`p_write` and `p_read`) which run on the same machine.

- Process `p_write` is for writing/updating the mmap file.
- Process `p_read` is for consuming the mmap file, or in other words, reading
  from the mmap file.

My assumption here is that `p_write` needs to first allocate a memory space (off-heap) for the mmap file (the space is mapped to the file automatically using the Java `MappedByteBuffer` API).

My question here is *how does p_read read from the mmap file?* My assumption now is that `p_read` also needs to allocate another same size off-heap space for the mmap file to be mapped to, but this seems incorrect as the amount of memory will need to be doubled in this scenario.

If `p_read` does not need to allocate a separate memory space for the mmap file to be mapped to, how does `p_read` know the right memory address that the file was mapped to by `p_write`?

**UPDATE 1**

I found a better question to ask, or you can consider this as a follow-up question:
If `FileChannel.map()` is called twice, will the same file be mapped twice into two different memory spaces?

```
// Scenario A: In single process

try (FileChannel fc = FileChannel.open(filePath, openOptions)) {
   // First call
   fc.map(MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, SIZE_CONSTANT);
   // Second call
   fc.map(MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, SIZE_CONSTANT);
}
```

And

```
// Scenario B: In two processes

// in first process
try (FileChannel fc = FileChannel.open(filePath, openOptions)) {
   // First call in first process
   fc.map(MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, SIZE_CONSTANT);
}
...
// in second process
try (FileChannel fc = FileChannel.open(filePath, openOptions)) {
   // Second call in second process
   fc.map(MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, SIZE_CONSTANT);
}
```

Maybe it does not really matter for the two scenarios, if they are all mapped into one same memory space?